# What is wrong with this JSON-RPC? (via BTC.com)

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, source-code

The subscribe message works. But the authorization does not. I was wondering why I cannot get this to work. The expected outcome is to have a miner that is logged in and has no errors in authorization, subscription, or in nonce capture. I am get this as a response to the code below it:

**Received: {"error":null,"id":1,"result":[[["mining.notify","0000ce121"],["mining.set_difficulty","0000ce122"]],"0000ce12",8]}**

**Authentication Response: {"error":null,"id":1,"result":false}**

```
# Subscribe to mining notifications
    subscribe_message = '{"id": 1, "method": "mining.subscribe", "params": []}\n'
    sock.sendall(subscribe_message.encode())
    
    # Receive and print the response
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    print(f'Received: {data.decode()}')
    
    # Extract the subscription ID and extranonce
    response_data = json.loads(data.decode())
    subscription_id = response_data['result'][1]
    extranonce1 = response_data['result'][1][1]

    # Authenticate (replace 'username' and 'password' with your actual credentials)
    auth_message = '{"id": 2, "method": "mining.authorize", "params": ["{username}", "{password}"]}\n'
    sock.sendall(auth_message.encode())
    
    # Receive and print the authentication response
    auth_response = sock.recv(1024)
    print(f'Authentication Response: {auth_response.decode()}')
```

i just joined this pool. BTC.com I am perhaps unknowing of its proper edict in username and password for joining the pool. What, if any knowledge you might have about this pool that could help me?

Comment: Okay, so the auth_message need not have quotes around username and password apparently. That was the answer.